# Migrating a model to a new app in Django 1.7.2 fails with ValueError at FK

Tags: django, orm, migration

Steps I took to move `Stores` model from `products` app to new `stores` app.  `products.Product` and `pages.Page` both have FK's to `stores.Store`.

1. Created new app with `./manage.py startapp stores`
2. Moved class from old to new models.py
3. Updated references to `Store` throughout (except in old migration scripts, which caused it to fail during makemigrations with similar error)
4. Added metadata in the model class pointing to the old table name place (see below)
5. Tested web app in browser, works fine
6. Created the migrations with `./manage.py makemigrations`
7. Tried to apply migrations `./manage.py migrate`, but blows up on a FK from a 3rd model `Page` and app in reference to `Store`.

The moved model:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products_store'
    ...
```

The model with broken reference:

```
from stores.models import Store
...
class Page(TimeStampedModel):
    ...
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='pages', null=True)
```

The brokenness:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying pages.0007_auto_20150112_0321...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 96, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 140, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File "/Users/john/.venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 94, in render
    raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model))
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field pages.Page.store: stores.Store
```

Python 2.7.6 and Django 1.7.2 on OSX 10.10.1.

**Update**

The migration script which is failing is `pages.0007_auto_20150112_0321`, on this operation:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='page',
        name='store',
        field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='pages', to='stores.Store', null=True),
        preserve_default=True,
    ),
```

Couple other observations:

I can create the FK above from a shell without a problem, but it works regardless of what `to` is set to. Not sure exactly what I should try here to reproduce the error.

If I change the "to" field to "lkjsdf" in the migration it gives the same type of error.

Also, if I run `./manage.py migrate stores` (specifying an app), then instead I get:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: stores
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    products | store

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
```

So it wants to delete all my references to `stores` which does not sound good.

Happy to provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the migration file itself - they're pretty readable, and the operations are documented. You should also post it here.

Comment: Thanks @KevinChristopherHenry. I've added more info.

Comment: Sometimes it can help to break things into separate steps to help the autodetector. Try creating the new app and model, but without changing the `ForeignKey`. Create a migration. Then change the `ForeignKey` reference to the new model and create another migration. See if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue check dependency in your failing migrations

Eg:

```
dependencies = [
    ('some_app', '0003_auto_20160713_0435'),
    ('stores', '0002_stores'),  # This is your latest migration in stores app
 ]
```

Try adding stores dependency to migration and try.